# Selecting random values from dataframe without replacement

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I am following the answer from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507752/selecting-random-values-from-dataframe):

If I have a dataframe df as:

```
Month   Day     mnthShape
1      1    1.01
1      1    1.09
1      1    0.96
1      2    1.01
1      1    1.09
1      2    0.96
1      3    1.01
1      3    1.09
1      3    1.78
```

I want to get the following from `df`:

```
Month   Day mnthShape
1       1   1.01
1       2   1.01
1       1   0.96
```

where the `mnthShape` values are selected at random from the index `without replacement`. i.e. if the query is `df.loc[(1, 1)]` it should look for all values for (1, 1) and select randomly from it a value to be displayed above. If another `df.loc[(1,1)]` appears it should select randomly again but without replacement.

I know I need to modify the code to use the following:

```
apply(np.random.choice, replace=False)
```

But not sure how to do it.

Edit:
Everytime I do `df.loc[(1, 1)]`, it should give new value without replacement. I intend to do `df.loc[(1, 1)]` multiple times. In the previous question, it was just one time.

Comment: Hard to understand and find the different between your previous  question

Comment: Does my comment make sense?

Comment: you can do with drop , every time get the df using drop drop the one already selected

Comment: I will have to write a for loop as my selection size is of order of 10,000. I was looking for more automated way or maybe I didn't understand your suggestion, do you mind presenting it through a code snippet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to sample from the dataset without replacement, it probably makes sense to do this all in one go, rather than iteratively pulling a sample from the dataset.

Pulling N samples from each month/day combo requires that there be sufficient combinations to pull N without replacement. But assuming this is true, you could write a function to sample N values from a subset of the data:

```
def select_n(subset, n=2):
    choices = np.random.choice(len(x), size=n, replace=False)
    return (
        subset
        .mnthShape
        .iloc[choices]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .rename_axis('choice'))
```

to apply this across the whole dataset:

```
In [34]: df.groupby(['Month', 'Day']).apply(select_n)
Out[34]:
choice        0     1
Month Day
1     1    1.09  0.96
      2    0.96  1.01
      3    1.09  1.01
```

If you really need to pull these one at a time, you'll still need to generate the samples all at once to guarantee that they're drawn without replacement, but you could generate the sample indices separately from subsetting the data:

```
In [48]: indices = np.random.choice(3, size=2, replace=False)

In [49]: df[((df.Month == 1) & (df.Day == 2))].iloc[indices[0]]
Out[49]:
Month        1.00
Day          2.00
mnthShape    1.01
Name: 3, dtype: float64

In [50]: df[((df.Month == 1) & (df.Day == 2))].iloc[indices[1]]
Out[50]:
Month        1.00
Day          2.00
mnthShape    0.96
Name: 5, dtype: float64
```