# Generate combinations by randomly selecting a row from multiple groups (using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which appears as following: (toy version below but the real df contains many more columns and `groups`)

```
group  sub  fruit
a      1    apple
a      2    banana
a      3    orange
b      1    pear
b      2    strawberry
b      3    cherry
c      1    kiwi
c      2    tomato
c      3    lemon
```

All `group`s have the same number of rows. I am trying to generate a new dataframe that contains all the combinations of `group` and `sub` by randomly selecting 1 row from each `group`.

Desired output:

```
combo  group  sub  fruit
1      a      1    apple
1      b      1    pear
1      c      1    kiwi
2      a      2    banana
2      b      2    strawberry
2      c      1    kiwi
3      a      3    orange
3      b      2    strawberry
3      c      1    kiwi
4      a      2    banana
4      b      2    strawberry
4      c      3    lemon
5      a      3    orange
5      b      3    cherry
5      c      3    lemon
...
```

In this particular example, I would expect 27 different `combo`s. This example seems helpful but I haven't been able to iteratively generate each combination: [Randomly select a row from each group using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507752/randomly-select-a-row-from-each-group-using-pandas)

Comment: There are actually 27 combinations (3*3*3), not 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` on the groups of indices:

```
from itertools import product

out = pd.concat({i: df.loc[list(idx)] for i, idx in
                 enumerate(product(*df.index.groupby(df['group']).values()), start=1)})
```

output:

```
     group  sub   fruit
1  0     a    1   apple
   3     b    1    pear
   6     c    1    kiwi
2  0     a    1   apple
   3     b    1    pear
...    ...  ...     ...
26 5     b    3  cherry
   7     c    2  tomato
27 2     a    3  orange
   5     b    3  cherry
   8     c    3   lemon

[81 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I don't understand your issue. The code it "*running*" for me (in the sense that it produces a single DataFrame as output without errors). If you want me to debug, provide a fully reproducible code that triggers the issue and provide your python/pandas versions.

Comment: Hi @mozway — thanks, I think that the bug actually isn't in your code, but with how large my actual dataset is. Thank you, though, for your help!

Comment: Ah, I realize that my larger dataset wasn't "running" since it is just quite large. I just posted a new question that further constrains the randomization. Would you by chance be able to take a look? Thanks again for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74396796/generate-combinations-by-systematically-selecting-rows-from-groups-using-pandas